# C# Dictionary Calculate sum of group values

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I'm currently working on an application in C#. Imagine a store front with a checkout. I have a dictionary structure with an **object as Key**, and an **int object counter as value**.

the structure looks like this:

```
Dictionary<myObject, int> items.
```

The basic idea is, to pass a dictionary of Items into a method. I'm only adding unique myObjects to the dictionary. The myObject  has a counter rule attached. Once the counter rule is full filled I want to do a calculation with all myObects in the dictionary.

The myObject looks like this:

```
public class myObject
{
    string ItemId { get; set; }
    Discount Discount { get; set; }
}

 public class Discount
 {
     public int Count { get; set; }
     public decimal Price { get; set; }
     public IDiscountHandler DiscountHandler => new DiscountHandler();
 }
```

A sample myObject could look like this:

```
 var myObectA = new myObject()
 {
     ItemId = "A"
 };

var discountA = new Discount()
{
    Count = 2,
    Price = 12 // special price, if 2 myObjects were added to the Dictionary
};

myObjectA.Discount = discountA;
```

1) I fill the items Dictionary and pass it to the Handler method:

```
private decimal _totalDiscountedValue { get; set; } = 0;

    if (!_items.ContainsKey(myObject))
    {
        _items.Add(myObject, 1);
    }
    else
    {
        _items[myObject]++;
    }

   _totalDiscountedValue += _discountHandler.CalculateDiscount(_items);
```

2) In my Handler I try to sum up all the discount values, once a counter rule is full filled. But here I'm struggling unfortunately:

```
public class DiscountHandler : DiscountHandler
{
    private decimal _totalDiscount { get; set; } = 0;

    public override decimal CalculateDiscount(IDictionary<myObject, int> items)
    {
        if (items == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(items));

        // I'm struggeling here: 
        // check if Dictionary[i].Dicount.Count = Dictionary.Value
        // then _totalDiscount += Dictionary[i].Discount.Price

        return _totalDiscount;
    }
}
```

Do you know how to solve this issue, or do you have an idea on how to possibly solve this?

Thank you very much !!

Comment: _totalDiscountedValue  = _totalDiscountedValue  + _discountHandler.CalculateDiscount(_items);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just iterate through the Dictionary using foreach as follows:

```
public override decimal CalculateDiscount(IDictionary<myObject, int> items)
{
    if (items == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(items));

    foreach (var kvp in items)
    {
        if (kvp.Key.Discount.Count == kvp.Value)
            _totalDiscount += kvp.Key.Discount.Price;
    }
    return _totalDiscount;
}
```

Comment: I prefer this answer due to the use of the guard clause

Comment: Do you mind explain what you mean by "guard clause" ? How is this answer any different from mine ?

Answer (score 3):

Using Linq

```
//check if yourDictonary is not null
var sum = yourDictonary.Select(x => x.Key.Discount.Count == x.Value).Sum(x => x.Value)
```

Comment: Nice use of Linq ! I didn't know about the sum method, thanks for that :-)

Answer (score 0):

IF I understood the problem properly, maybe doing this would work

```
foreach (var item in items)
{
    if (item.Key.Discount.Count == item.Value)
        _totalDiscount += item.Key.Discount.Price;
}

return __totalDiscount;
```

Comment: `Key.Dicount` should be `Key.Discount`, OP has the same typo, and for checking equality in an if statement, use `==` instead of `=`. Syntax! ;)

Comment: oh, my bad ! i should definitely test-run my code before giving an answer, that `=` is bad ! thanks you <3